# ld - output file is empty

Tags: build, ld

I am trying to write a kernel in assembly and C++ (I'm still on assembly right now), and I'm loading it with GRUB. So far, everything works fine, except for linking. I'm using `ld`, and even though the input files are not empty, it produces an empty binary.

Here is my build script:

```
@echo off
nasm -f elf64 multiboot_header.asm
nasm -f elf64 boot.asm
ld --nmagic --output=kernel.bin --script=linker.ld multiboot_header.o boot.o
move /Y kernel.bin isofiles/boot/kernel.bin
wsl grub-mkrescue -o os.iso isofiles
rem del *.o
```

and my linker.ld script:

```
ENTRY(start)

SECTIONS {
    . = 1M;

    .boot :
    {
        /* ensure that the multiboot header is at the beginning */
        *(.multiboot_header)
    }

    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I was accidentally using ld from MinGW, instead of from Linux gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said: Accidentally using ld.exe from MinGW can cause this to happen (as opposed to the ld.exe from Linux gcc)